# calculation time reducing c++ optimization

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, time

Here is my code that need to process 100*250 000 data in less than 3s 
As i'm quite new to coding, what can i improve or change to make it faster, and more optimized ?
Here is the code chef page to the problem : https://www.codechef.com/problems/DEFOREST

```
// codechef_deforestation.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    //Read input
    freopen("C:\\somepath\\input.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("C:\\somepath\\output.out", "w", stdout);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    //std::cout << t << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        double result = -1;
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        //std::cout << t << std::endl;
        std::vector <int> x, h;
        x.resize(n);
        h.resize(n);
        //chargement des données
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cin >> x[j] >> h[j];
            //std::cout << x[j] << h[j] << std::endl;
        }
        //calcul
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++)
            {
                //std::cout << "k : " << k << std::endl;
                int diff_x = x[k] - x[j];
                int diff_h = h[k] - h[j];
                if (diff_x == diff_h) //si 45 deg
                {
                    double res_int = sqrt(diff_x*diff_x + diff_h* diff_h);
                    for (int l = j + 1; l < k; l++)
                    {
                        //std::cout << "l : " << l << std::endl;
                        if (h[l] > x[l])
                        {
                            res_int = res_int - (h[l] - x[l]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (res_int > result)
                    {
                        result = res_int;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << result << std::endl;
        x.clear();
        h.clear();
    }
    clock_t testTime=clock();
    std::cout << testTime - startTime;
    return 0;
}
```

The freopen() fonction needs to stay

Comment: For working code I think [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) may be a better place to ask this.

Comment: You don't say how long it takes now; what hardware spec (potato or greater); what you have already tried.

Comment: A common bottleneck is I/O.  You may want to block read into a buffer then parse the buffer.

Comment: Profile.  Profiling will help identify where in your code most of the time is spent.

Comment: You may want to declare `diff_x` and `diff_h` as `const int`.  This may help the compiler perform better optimizations.

Comment: What compiler and optimization settings are you using?  Are you building in release or debug mode?

Comment: You need an algorithm with better than quadratic complexity. No amount of tweaking will make your brute force approach fast enough.

Comment: I don't see much room for optimizing your implementation; the optimization techniques may produce a negligible gain in performance.